# From two lists make one, putting second list values below first

Tags: r

For example I have two lists:

```
a = c(2, 3, 5) 
b = c("aa", "bb", "cc") 
c = c(TRUE, FALSE, TRUE) 
df = data.frame(a, b, c)
df1=split(df, df$b)
```

and

```
a = c(1, 2, 3) 
b = c("aa", "bb", "cc") 
c = c(TRUE, FALSE, TRUE) 
df2 = data.frame(a, b, c)
df3=split(df2, df2$b)
```

I want one combined df1 and df3 list like this:

```
$aa
  a  b    c
1 2 aa TRUE
4 1 aa TRUE

$bb
  a  b     c
2 3 bb FALSE
5 2 bb FALSE

$cc
  a  b    c
3 5 cc TRUE
6 3 cc TRUE
```

This is fully example data.

df1 values must be above df3 values in new one list.

I'm forecasting data by lists and I get my time series list and forecast list in two lists, so I want to combine them adding forecast values below.

Comment: input is `df1` and `df3`, and outpur is `df5` ?

Comment: Yes, from list - df1 and list - df3 i want combined list df5.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Map(rbind, df1, df3)

$aa
a  b    c
1 2 aa TRUE
4 1 aa TRUE

$bb
  a  b     c
2 3 bb FALSE
5 2 bb FALSE

$cc
  a  b    c
3 5 cc TRUE
6 3 cc TRUE
```

Comment: Sorry for not being specific but df5 list must be created from df1 and df3 without setting names because real file is way bigger

Comment: You cannot not set names. You desired output has names "g" "h" and "k" that are mentioned nowhere else. And `df1` and `df3` have different names so can't be bound together without renaming, unless you convert them to matrix, which will be much worse performance wise.

Comment: You could use `Vectorize(data.table::setnames,"x",SIMPLIFY = F)(df1,c("g","h","k"))` (and same on `df3`) to rename your source tables by reference, and then just do `Map(rbind, df1, df3)`. I doubt that this setNames would be problematic performance wise though.

Comment: With your edited question the solution becomes very compact :)

Answer (score 0):

why not simply

```
n = c(2, 3, 5, 2, 3, 5) 
s = c("aa", "bb", "cc") 
b = c(TRUE, FALSE, TRUE,TRUE, FALSE, TRUE) 
df = data.frame(n, s, b)
df1=split(df, df$s)

a = c(1, 2, 3) 
c = c("aa", "bb", "cc") 
d = c(TRUE, FALSE, TRUE) 
df2 = data.frame(a, c, d)
df3=split(df2, df2$c)

g = c(n,a) 
h = c("aa", "bb", "cc") 
k = c(b,d)
df4 = data.frame(g, h, k)
df5=split(df4, df4$h)
```